# Passing objects from PHP to SOAP Web Service with structs

Tags: php, web-services, object, soap, struct

I am connecting to a SOAP web service from a web application written in PHP, and I'm having issues getting the service to accept the objects I am attempting to send it.  But only sometimes, and I can't figure out why particular objects are successfully passed while others are not.

I'm using PHP's SoapClient class, and if I use the __getFunctions() and __getTypes() methods, I get the following response:  (For brevity's sake I will not list every single method and type)

This is the postOrder method I want to use within the webservice:

```
string(323) "respOrder postOrder(string $siteId, string $secretKey, string $language, string $customerName, string $emailAddress, parmAddress $deliveryAddress, parmAddress $billingAddress, parmCreditCard $creditCard, string $cvv, parmOrderLineArray $orderLines, string $shippingCharge, string $reference, string $poNumber, string $text)"
```

And here is an example of the object that is giving me trouble, parmAddress:

```
  [1]=>
  string(176) "struct parmAddress {
 string addressLine1;
 string addressLine2;
 string addressLine3;
 string city;
 string countryCode;
 string name;
 string postalCode;
 string stateCode;
}
```

I have attempted to construct this particular object in a number of different ways.  Using the PHP stdObject, creating an object of a PHP class named parmAddress, and even sending an array.  Unfortunately, the response I get from the web service is always the following.  In this example I am just passing an object of one of the types I define below:

```
    //The type of object I send
    class parmAddress{
    public $addressLine1 = '891 Prairie Grass Drive';
    public $addressLine2 = '';
    public $addressLine3 = '';
    public $city = 'Las Vegas';
    public $countryCode = '1';
    public $name = 'Eric Dodson';
    public $postalCode = '89123';
    public $stateCode = 'NV';
    }

    //Or I've tried the stdObject as mentioned above
     $obj = new stdClass();
     $obj->addressLine1= '';
     $obj->addressLine2= '';
     $obj->addressLine3 = '';
     $obj->city = 'Las Vegas';
     $obj->countryCode = '1';
     $obj->name = 'Eric Dodson';
     $obj->postalCode = '89123';
     $obj->stateCode = 'NV';

    //Making the object and using the postOrder() method
    $parmaddress = new parmAddress();
    $order = $client->postOrder('user', 'pass', 'en', 'Eric Dodson', 'dodson@dodson.com', $parmaddress, $parmaddress, $parmcreditcard, '123', $parmorderlinearray, 0.00, 'No Comments');

    //The response given to me by the webservice
    object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
      ["code"]=>
      string(7) "failure"
      ["message"]=>
      string(21) "Invalid address name."
      ["orderNumber"]=>
      int(0)
    }
```

Oddly enough, I have had success sending other objects in what seems to be exactly the same way.  For example, if I create the parmPart object in an identical fashion, and pass it with this getParts() method in the parmPartArray it asks for, it is successful.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->availabilityCode = '';
$obj->availableQuantity = '';
$obj->listPrice = '';
$obj->manufacturerCode = 'RPL';
$obj->partNumber = '341241';
$obj->price = '';
$obj->substitute = '';

$partsarray = array(
        0 => $obj
);

$partsresponsearray = $client->getParts('user', 'pass', 'en', $partsarray);
```

I'm think it is important to note the web service wants to be sent structs which I am fairly unfamiliar with, and I'm hoping my problem will lie therein.  The developer of the web service was able to tell me the following, but I haven't been able to find any additional information on sending objects from PHP to a web service that wants structs:

"That message is issued when the address name attribute is not filled. I remember for composite type like this parmAddress you have to "encode" it in PHP. I am not sure about the syntax now."

So apparently the web service thinks my "name" string is empty, and there is some type of encoding I must do to make it recognize what I am sending it.  Any ideas?  Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

As requested by another user, here is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. 
    RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-b01-. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. 
    RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-b01-. -->
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://ws.reliableparts.net/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.reliableparts.net/"
    name="RetailOrderServerService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.reliableparts.net/"
                schemaLocation="http://www.reliableparts.net/dataservicetc/retail?xsd=1" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getParts">
        <part name="siteId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="secretKey" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="language" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="parts" type="tns:parmPartArray" />
    </message>
    <message name="getPartsResponse">
        <part name="return" type="tns:parmPartArray" />
    </message>
    <message name="postOrder">
        <part name="siteId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="secretKey" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="language" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="customerName" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="emailAddress" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="deliveryAddress" type="tns:parmAddress" />
        <part name="billingAddress" type="tns:parmAddress" />
        <part name="creditCard" type="tns:parmCreditCard" />
        <part name="cvv" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="orderLines" type="tns:parmOrderLineArray" />
        <part name="shippingCharge" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="reference" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="poNumber" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="text" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="postOrderResponse">
        <part name="return" type="tns:respOrder" />
    </message>
    <portType name="RetailOrderServer">
        <operation name="getParts" parameterOrder="siteId secretKey language parts">
            <input message="tns:getParts" />
            <output message="tns:getPartsResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="postOrder"
            parameterOrder="siteId secretKey language customerName emailAddress deliveryAddress billingAddress creditCard cvv orderLines shippingCharge reference poNumber text">
            <input message="tns:postOrder" />
            <output message="tns:postOrderResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="RetailOrderServerPortBinding" type="tns:RetailOrderServer">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
            style="rpc" />
        <operation name="getParts">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.reliableparts.net/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.reliableparts.net/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="postOrder">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.reliableparts.net/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.reliableparts.net/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="RetailOrderServerService">
        <port name="RetailOrderServerPort" binding="tns:RetailOrderServerPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.reliableparts.net/dataservicetc/retail" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Here are the results of using $client->__getLastRequest()

```
xmlns:ns1="http://ws.reliableparts.net/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:postOrder>
         <siteId>REDACTED</siteId>
         <secretKey>REDACTED</secretKey>
         <language>en</language>
         <customerName>Eric Dodson</customerName>
         <emailAddress>dodson@dodson.com</emailAddress>
         <deliveryAddress id="ref1">
            <addressLine1>891 Prairie Grass Drive</addressLine1>
            <addressLine2 />
            <addressLine3 />
            <city>Las Vegas</city>
            <countryCode>1</countryCode>
            <name>Eric Dodson</name>
            <postalCode>89123</postalCode>
            <stateCode>NV</stateCode>
         </deliveryAddress>
         <deliveryAddress href="#ref1" />
         <creditCard>
            <expirationDate>201605</expirationDate>
            <number>4111111111111111</number>
            <type>Visa</type>
         </creditCard>
         <cvv>123</cvv>
         <orderLines>
            <item>
               <manufacturerCode>RPL</manufacturerCode>
               <partNumber>341241</partNumber>
               <price>$99.99</price>
               <quantity>1</quantity>
               <text>No Comments</text>
            </item>
         </orderLines>
         <shippingCharge>0</shippingCharge>
         <reference>string</reference>
         <poNumber>string</poNumber>
         <text>string</text>
      </ns1:postOrder>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you sending an array for each `parmAddress`? They should be individual objects, not an array (like partsarray is). Show how you call `postOrder()`. Can you show the WSDL?

Comment: I am not sending an array for parmAddress, just an individual object.  I will add the way I call postOrder() to the original post, as well as add the WSDL.  Thanks for the question I'm sure that will help in my post's clarity!

Comment: Can you show the result of `$client->__getLastRequest()` (after you make the call to `postOrder()`). To use this you must set the trace option on the client e.g. `$client = SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));`

Comment: Also, you aren't setting the last 2 params (poNumber, text).

Comment: I showed the result of $client->__getLastRequest() above and experimented with the two missing fields.  The poNumber and text additions unfortunately did not solve my problem either